# D3 - Center the globe to the clicked country

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

In the example below, I see that when a user selects a country, the globe rotates and centers to that country. How can I code it such that when a country is clicked, the globe centers to that country?

[D3 Globe](http://plnkr.co/edit/MeAA55fbY5dMZETCXpFo?p=preview)

I have tried to do add an on click handler before the mouseover event, but it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

```
.on("click", function(d) {
    var rotate = projection.rotate(),
    focusedCountry = country(countries, this),
    p = d3.geo.centroid(focusedCountry);
    svg.selectAll(".focused").classed("focused", focused = false);

    //Globe rotating

    (function transition() {
     d3.transition()
     .duration(2500)
     .tween("rotate", function() {
            var r = d3.interpolate(projection.rotate(), [-p[0], -p[1]]);
            return function(t) {
            projection.rotate(r(t));
            svg.selectAll("path").attr("d", path)
            .classed("focused", function(d, i) { return d.id == focusedCountry.id ? focused = d : false; });
            };
            })
     })();
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First create a click to the path like this:

```
 .on("click", function(d){rotateMe(d);})
```

Change code for the clicked data. Get the id of the clicked path and get its country data.

```
var rotateMe =  function(d) {
  var rotate = projection.rotate(),
  focusedCountry = country(countries, d.id),//get the clicked country's details
  p = d3.geo.centroid(focusedCountry);
  console.log(focusedCountry, "hello")
  svg.selectAll(".focused").classed("focused", focused = false);

//Globe rotating

(function transition() {
  d3.transition()
  .duration(2500)
  .tween("rotate", function() {
    var r = d3.interpolate(projection.rotate(), [-p[0], -p[1]]);
    return function(t) {
      projection.rotate(r(t));
      svg.selectAll("path").attr("d", path)
      .classed("focused", function(d, i) { return d.id == focusedCountry.id ? focused = d : false; });
    };
  })
  })();
};
```

working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/AzianFOknvgRBR2f7TvC?p=preview)

Comment: do you know what's funny? If you pass the international date line, the globe will rotate back! For instance: rotate the globe two or three times, and position a given country close to the center. If you click on that country, you'd expect the globe to rotate a little bit and center the country, right? But, instead, it will rotate back those two or three times, and then center the country!

Comment: nopes! could not recreate that :) tried it many times but found nothing unusual ...

Comment: Really? Maybe just my browser? Try this: your projection starts with western Africa on the centre. Move the projection towards west (making the globe spin the normal way, from west to east), until you get Australia in the very centre of projection. Now click on Australia. In my browser, the globe spins a complete turn to the east and then centers on Australia.

Comment: Nopes tried on FF ver 28 os: linux ubuntu and chrome(ver:47.0.2526.80) cant recreate..did exactly as you instructed..strange.

Comment: Very much, indeed! I'm using windows 7 64, and it happens in both Chrome 49 and FF 45!

Comment: I see Gerardo's issue. The way to replicate is: Center your map at the US. Then slowly drag the globe till you barely see Australia on the west of US. Then click on the visible part of Australia. The globe spins all the way east and then centers at Australia. The key here is to barely see Australia on the west of the US. You might have to try this a couple of times to see this effect.

Comment: Funny, isn't Jake? In my case, I'm putting Australia right in the centre, and even so the world spins after the click.